# Android cocos2d how to take screenshot of CCscene?

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-android

I have a CCScene in one my CCLayer class, i need to take screen shot of it and save as Image file. Please help me to get it.

```
    View myView = findViewById(R.id.form);
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap( myView.getMeasuredWidth() , myView.getMeasuredHeight() , Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
myView.draw(canvas);
try {
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( "/sdcard/screen.jpg" );
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
out.flush();
out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {

e.printStackTrace();

}
```

This code didnt worked out. Returns 0kb image file.
I need it in java.

Answer (score 0):

If CCRenderTexture is available in the Android port I suggest using that. I have an [example here](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/12/how-to-use-ccrendertexture-motion-blur-screenshots-drawing-sketches/), even though it's for iPhone it should generally show the basic use of CCRenderTexture.